# Get All Carrier Lists in a Core PHP file

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping, shipping-methods, external

Want to fetch all Carrier Names in a .PHP file
In a Core PHP file which is available in a inner folder of Magento,

**For Ex.** MagentoRootFolder/CorePHPFolder/File.php**

For Using Magento Code Externally I am using following Code :

```
<?php
require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
// extra code 
?>
<select>
    <?php 
        // **Here I need Code** to Get *All Shipping Carrier List*
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear? What do you mean by the $this object. Do you want to use Magento core functionality? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sander, Forget about $this, I want to get Courier List in a Core PHP file which is available in a inner folder of Magento, **For Ex.** MagentoRoot/CorePHPFolder/File.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Config` model you can get a list of active carriers, their code in Magento and the model used for that carrier.

```
Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
```

returns an array with the code as *key*, the model as *value*.

To get the name or any other `System > Configuration` value you could use the code

```
Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/{$code}/title");
```

Comment: its providing following output : http://postimg.org/image/no8eiyzcn/  in print_r(Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers());

Comment: yes, that is correct, it's an object

Comment: But I am not seeing any courier name in it. :(

Comment: You could use the code to retrieve the name field from the core_config_data table. Updated my answer

Comment: Hmm alright, i try my efforts too.. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for all the carriers, use the below code for reference.

```
<code>
$carriersData = array();
$carriers = Mage::getsingleton("shipping/config")->getAllCarriers();
foreach($carriers as $code => $method){
    $carriersData[$code] = array(
        "title"     => Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$code/title"),
        "methods"   => $method->getMethods(),
     );
}
</code>
```

That will get you all the shipping modules, even if there are custom ones installed from other modules.

Answer (score 1):

Robs answer is great, but if you just need the custom once like in my case then the following

```
$carriers = array();
$carrierInstances = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getAllCarriers();
$carriers['custom'] = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Custom Value');
foreach ($carrierInstances as $code => $carrier) {
    if ($carrier->isTrackingAvailable()) {
        $carriers[$code] = $carrier->getConfigData('title');
    }
}
```